# Submitting nested class within a model to a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to submit a form with a model that has a nested class within it.  However when I get the data to the controller, the nested class has null fields.

Model:

```
 public class Person
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ExtraStuff Stuff { get; set; } = new ExtraStuff();
 }

   public class ExtraStuff 
   {
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    public string Field2 { get; set; }

  }
```

View:

```
@model ProjectName.Models.Person

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Stuff.Field1)  
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Stuff.Field2)
```

Controller:

```
   public ActionResult ActionName (Person data)
    {
      data.Name       //this is fine
      data.Stuff.Field1 //comes in empty
      data.Stuff.Field2 //comes in empty
    }
```

Comment: A controller calls a deserialize method to parse the response.  The answer depends on the deserialize method that is used.  Most case the response is either JSON (Java) or XML.  Java deserialize methods does not need to be instantiate while xml does.

Comment: In your Controller, try `data.Stuff.Field1`  -- Person has Stuff of type ExtraStuff, and you're trying to access ExtraStuff instead of Stuff.  Also, your view should have `model.Stuff.Field1`.

Comment: I corrected my post.  The fields remain empty though.  Why doesn't it get the textbox content from the form?

Comment: You need to be looking for data.Stuff in your controller, not data.ExtraStuff.  Also, check your POST body using F12 dev tools, network tab.  Is the data you expect to see in the payload?  And if so, what does it look like?

Comment: Looking at DevTools, those two fields are empty upon submission.  I have content in the textbox.  What could be causing that?

Comment: You have to present an [mcve] because it works like this for me.

Comment: If those 2 fields are empty in the POST payload, the problem is not in your Controller.  It's with your form submission or your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering if you're doing some custom form submission, because there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code provided. If you make a form like the following it should work:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "MyController"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TopValue)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nested.SomeValue)
                
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

Take a look at [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wQo896) for example.

Comment: You know what, this is an Ajax call and I did not add the extra fields it to the Ajax code.  Only the form and the controller.